# React nested route render the parent component with the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am learning about React (Coming from ASP.NET). When I go to `'/employee'` it will display employee list table. But when I go to `'/employee/create'` it will display both the table and the create form. How to display only create employee form when I to `'/employee/create'` ?

```
export default class App extends Component {
static displayName = App.name;

render() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
            <AuthorizeRoute path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
            <Route exact path='/employee' component={EmployeeIndex} />
            <Route path='/employee/create' component={EmployeeCreate} />
            <Route path='/employee/details/:id' component={EmployeeDetails} />
            
        </Layout>
    );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To do that, you will need to add a `<Switch>` around your `Routes`:**

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";


<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
   <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
   <AuthorizeRoute path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
   <Route exact path='/employee' component={EmployeeIndex} />
   <Route path='/employee/create' component={EmployeeCreate} />
   <Route path='/employee/details/:id' component={EmployeeDetails} />
</Switch>
```

It works just like a normal `switch-case, will only render the first matching path within your Routes.

Without `<Switch>` it will render **ALL** matching routes.

Comment: I had to move `<Route exact path='/employee' component={EmployeeIndex} />` to bottom, before `</Switch>`, to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I use in my apps.
Make separate components for all pages and import in App.js under src. Make use of state and props to store the data and create ID. Install **npm i react-router-dom** to access react route.

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/employee" component={Employee} />
    <Route exact path="/createEmployee" component={Create} />
    <Route exact path="/employeeDetails" component={Details} />
    <Redirect to = "/" />   
</Switch>
```

1. for homepage - Home.js
2. for employee list table - Employee.js
3. create employee - Create.js
4. go to employee's detail - Details.js
5. Redirect to - will redirect to homepage if exact URL is not entered.